# Room working with own objects in a database (sub-entities in entity)

Tags: java, android, android-room

I've been studying such time to find out the best and the easiest solution to this problem.
Let's say that I want to put an entity into another entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
public class User {

   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
   private Long id;

   @ColumnInfo(name = "firstName")
   private String firstName;

   @ColumnInfo(name = "lastName")
   private String lastName;


   //getters & setters
}
```

The ORMLite supports to storage own objects (entities) into another entity and also it contains in a table (not like @Embedded in Room). But what I found out the Room does not support something like this. So my solution is to add ids of that entities to target entity. (This code bellow was cut from User entity, above the comment)

```
   @ForeignKey(entity = Photo.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "userPhotoId")
   @ColumnInfo(name = "userPhotoId")
   private Long userPhotoId;

   @ForeignKey(entity = Home.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "userHomeId")
   @ColumnInfo(name = "userHomeId")
   private Long userHomeId;
```

and besides that, I should add my entities with @Ignore annotation like

```
   @Ignore
   private Photo userPhoto;

   @Ignore
   private House userHome;
```

then I have getters & setters for data managing.

Now I am using this way to set data. In my opinion, this is a very complicated solution.

```
public void insertUser(@NonNull User user) {
    new AsyncTask<User, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(User... users) {
            User newUser = users[0];

            Photo photo = newUser.getUserPhoto();
            House home = newUser.getUserHome();
            Long photoId = dao.insert(photo);
            Long houseId = dao.insert(home);

            newUser.setUserPhotoId(photoId);
            newUser.setUserHouseId(houseId);

            dao.insert(newUser);
            return null;
        }
    }.execute(user);
}
```

And about the get data logic, I am using observers.

```
LiveData<User> userLiveData = dao.getUserById(userId);
userLiveData.observeForever(new Observer<User>() {
   @Override
   public void onChanged(@Nullable User user) {
   //...
   //the last line will remove an observer before ending.                      
   userLiveData.removeObserver(this);
}
```

It looks easy, but if you want to get more data form a DB, it becomes more complicated.
 And this is not what I am looking for. My ideas are like

```
User user = getUserById(..);
user.getPhoto();
//...
//and working without worries
```

or

```
insertUser(myUser);
//and I am sure that the sub-entities were added automatically without any special logic
```

What I am looking for is the best (and the easiest as well) solution to send/receive data from the database entity with entities if my queries return **LiveData**s.

*Or if you have any better experiences, I'll be thankful for any useful response.*

Thanks for any ideas, I think this might be helpful for many people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this after one week. So I would like to share it.
So my recommendation is to use Threads (or AsyncTasks for Android) with ViewModel and do not use LiveDatas.

Check this code bellow.

```
public class MyMV extends AndroidViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<User> userLiveData = new MutableLiveData();

    //main logic for getting data from a db
    public void getUser(long userId) {
       new Thread(()-> {
          //do not use the '.setValue()', a post method will send a result to observers immediately
          userLiveData.postValue(new User(dao.getUserById(userId));
       }).start();
    }

    //UserLiveData getter
    public LiveData<User> getUserData() {
        return userLiveData;
    }
}
```

Let's move to an activity or somewhere on UI

```
//an observer is something like listener
myVM.getUserData().observe(this, user -> {
  //here we can work with user
});
```

If you have troubles with view model, you can check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).